# Nginx proxy_pass without get / post parameters

Tags: post, nginx, proxy, get

I'm doing proxy_pass when url of my domain looks like this:

http://evil.corp/v666/this/is/my/url

and everything works fine.

```
location ~^/v666/ {
  proxy_pass http://evil.corp.lan;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

evil.corp.lan has second nginx and I'm proxing the request.

But I wish to CUT the part "/v666" after the domain, and proxy only this part of my url:

http://evil.corp/this/is/my/url

without "/v666"

could you give me hint how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean to replace any URI with `/`. Just append it to the `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: After the domain name, cut the /v666 part, and leave the rest of the url unchanged.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/586614/211028

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
location /v666/ {
```

and

```
proxy_pass http://evil.corp.lan:80/;
```

helped.

https://serverfault.com/a/725433/331458

It is very important to use

> location /v666/

otherwise, using location ~^/v666/ you will end up with:

"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block.

Now it works! :)